# Can I move the mouse pointer in flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, mouse

I am building a virtual mouse kind of app, so is there any way in flutter by which I can move the mouse pointer to a specific coordinate on the screen.
I know there is a Robot class in java which can do the exact thing, so is there something similar in Flutter(Dart)
Note: I am not referring to the MouseRegion Widget kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality built into Flutter, but you could [write a plugin](https://flutter.dev/desktop#writing-a-plugin) that would do that.

Comment: I really cannot imagine how to start writing a plugin for this functionality @smorgan can u please give me a headstart?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for exactly. A plugin that defines a method on the Dart side and implements it with native code is the standard case created by the plugin template.